# Basic description of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is all the possible polynomials in $x$ with integer coefficients:

$\mathbb{Z}[x]=\{a_0+a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots:a_n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Where $a_n$ are not all necessarily distinct. Modding out by $x$ basically cuts the polynomials off at the first power of $x$, as I understand it, so that

$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)=\{a_0 + a_1 x:a_0,a_1\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Is everything I said here correct? Are there any other obvious things I should be able to say about this ring?

Comment: You can also say $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ via the evaluation map at $x=0$.

Comment: Not quite, you cut off the polynomials *before* $x$, i.e. $\{a_0:a_0\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.  Think of modding out by $x$ as setting $x=0$.  This also sets $x^2=0$, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're not right. The ring you are searching has the particular relation that x=0, so it will be all the polynomials of grade zero, and so all the costants, which is actually $\mathbb{Z}$